Determine dropout spacing for vintage bike frame online
I've been trying to find a decent steel-frame mountain bike on Facebook marketplace, and there are many catalogs available with specs like this one. However, so far as I can tell they only give the profile of the frame geometry, and so it's not possible to determine the dropout spacing. This is important because I am interested in upgrading the freewheel/cassette to a higher number of gears.
Is there anywhere I can look online, or are there any rules of thumb, that could give me information on the dropout spacing? Obviously the best thing to do would be to measure, but that is somewhat difficult when perusing the marketplace.

In addition to mattnz's answer, if you find a frame with 130 spacing, you can use a road hub or fit a road axle to a shimano mountain hub if you would rather not change the frame. The hub shell for shimano hubs are the same for road and mountain at Deore/Tiagra level and others.

@Noise _ That is a good point, I was not aware of that compatibility.

Can you ask the seller to measure with a ruler?  Point them at a photo showing exactly how you want them to do the measurement.

If all you are after is a steel frame, consider looking for something newer - while not insurmountable, parts compatibility problems do not stop at the hub.  A newer frame would mean off the shelf parts rather than used or hunting out "new old stock" from niche suppliers.
A few manufacturers continued to make steel frames even today - e.g. Jamis Dragon. A newer frame will have less problems finding compatible parts and will you will be able to get better parts (quality has improved) and have a wider choice.
MTB 6/7 speed were mostly 130mm, when they went up to 135mm in the early 1990's. Very early (1980's) could be 126mm though as that era was made from available parts - mostly road bike bits. A 1980's bike will be steel, which can be cold spread fairly successfully, You may also be able to shag around worth a 130mm hub and drop the OLD by using thinner lock nuts and changing cones. No guarantee of success, but if you can drop a couple of mm, might make a big difference to how much the frame needs spreading.
Most likely the frame will be 130mm in which case you can build a wheel with a 130mm hub. 126mm hubs are available but likely to be freewheel which will severely limit your cassette options for wider gearing.

To your point about a newer bike: a lot of my reasoning is cost. I can get a 90s trek/diamondback/fuji bike for $50-$150 on the marketplace, but a new Jamis Dragon costs $2,500, and a used one costs around $500. The other point is that I'm not really looking to mountain bike, I just want a cruiser that will last a while, so a suspension fork/disc brakes/1x is out of the question. I appreciate the word of caution though, many of my questions on here are about compatibility/maintaining old parts.

These old MTBs make great everyday bikes, but compromising on specs is normally best for value. That may mean sticking with the gears it came with.

This article should give you some rules of thumb for spacing based on gearing. Also, Sheldon Brown (RIP) has a huge number of useful articles about bikes on that website.

Appreciate the link to that article. I remember seeing the table, but there's some crossover (e.g. MTB 7 speed could be 130mm or 135mm) for which differentiating info isn't really given.
